# How can I clear iOS IAP receipts for non-consumables on test devices?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

In attempting to clear non-consumable sandbox IAP receipts from my test device, I have tried:

- use a different sandbox test user DONE
- delete app from XCode organizer   DONE

Still didn't work, so I suspected that the receipt may be being restored from my iCloud account, even though this shouldn't be happening for a sandbox purchase. Therefore I also tried:

- removing iCloud entitlements from my app build, signing into a new test user account, deleting the app, deploying locally   DONE

Still no luck.

BTW, I'm using MKStoreKit.

Anybody have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you called `[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] removeAllKeychainData]` ?  Have you signed out of the iTunes account in the device preferences? Are you sure that you have never purchased this item with the test account you are using?

Comment: @Paulw11 `removeAllKeychainData` did it. Thanks so much for the answer! If you repost as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps :

1) sign out from iTunes account.

2) call **[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] removeAllKeychainData]** method

3) call in app code and on popup enter User detail and password.

this works for me.